# On IIS port 80 is timing out, but 443 returning the page immediately over port 80

Tags: windows, http, ssl, iis, https

I have a self hosted site running on IIS.  Worked perfectly.  Used win-acme to generate a cert.  My bindings are 80 first and 443 second.  My cert ran out and has failed to renew.  It's failing because port 80 (http) is timing out.  The weird part is that when I try to connect over https (443), it fails to connect, but then instantly loads the http site with a warning that the connection is not secure!  Therefore can't be firewall related.

Nothing has changed on the host, apart from the cert running out.  Any ideas anyone, I've run out and am now considering trying to beat it into line with a big stick!

Thanks in advance

Jim

Comment: Show your exact site bindings please (which are more than just ports). Besides, to prove "instantly loads the http site", see into IIS log files for log entries on port 80 please. Without those you cannot say "Therefore can't be firewall related" yet.

Comment: It may also be caused by the cache. You can try clearing the cache and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Too smart/confident for my own good!  Knew the router was 100% as I'd set it up myself.  Turns out somebody had been on there and deleted the port 80 NAT entry.  Sigh...